# What is support for an end-to-end and peer-to-peer transparent clock?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, clock, ethernet, phy

In the datasheet of [LAN9353](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/LAN9353), the description states that it supports "supports end-to-end and peer-to-peer transparent clocks"

Can someone tell me what is the meaning of this?

Comment: "Transparent" means the devices at both ends don't need to know anything is different than normal to use whatever is there. They just behave as if nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your quote omits information what it refers to. Here is better quote from the marketing material:

> IEEE 1588v2 is supported via the integrated IEEE 1588v2 hardware time stamp unit, which supports end-to-end and peer-to-peer transparent clocks.

It just means that the chip has built in hardware features to support the IEEE 1588v2 protocol over Ethernet.

Comment: Could you please explain me in similar terms on what that means? Peer to peer transparent clocks?